# SignalR disconnect not being called on internet disconnection/re-connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using SignalR in my app.I have an app which depends to a very great degree on `OnDisconnected()` being called correctly. And it is called correctly under the following circumstances:

```
 public Task OnDisconnected()
 {
     try
     {
        DeleteUser(Context.ConnectionId);
        return null;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        return null;
     }
}
```

1. The user refreshes the page
2. The user navigates to a new page
3. The user closes the browser

However, it is not called if the network connection suddenly drops. For instance, if I unplug the network cable on the client machine, or disable the client's wireless network, or unplug the router, `OnDisconnected()` will never get called, even after a several minute wait.

Comment: I havent worked with SignalR that much, but im pretty sure its not one of its functionallities to check, if user is still connected to a hub. You may want to implement your own timer which will log user out after (x) minutes.

Comment: Just feld over this link, it might be helpfull to you: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=826

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will raise disconnected but not immediately. There's configurable a threshold (30 seconds by default) that SignalR will wait (after the underlying tcp connection has gone away and this isn't immediate either) before it considers a client disconnected. If the connection drops and reconnects before the configured timeout then it won't raise OnDisconnected.

If you're never seeing it being raised in some scenario after waiting for a while then it might be a bug. SignalR 1.0 was released today so I'd encourage you to try that as well and see if you still see the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks dfowler..i will use signal r 1.0,now i am using signal r 0.5.3

Comment: David, is `HttpContext.Response.ClientDisconnectedToken` honored when we are hosting SignalR under ASP.NET 4.5 + IIS 8.0?

Comment: We don't use it because there's a bug in it. But when it's fixed we'll use it.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the right answer but this is what I know:

You won't be able to see the `OnDisconnected` event fired suddenly when the connection is dropped because SignalR doesn't track it down (it pools for connection with a background task to see if connection is dead within a certain interval). When you close the browser, I'm guessing that SignalR sends a request to server to signal the disconnect event. That's why you suddenly see the event fired.

However, ASP.NET 4.5 has a `CancellationToken` property called `ClientDisconnectedToken` for `HttpContext.Response` which is signaled when TCP connection is dropped. This only works under IIS 8.0 as far as I know and I'm not sure if SignalR works with this under .NET 4.5 ASP.NET host.